# UnwindResume and other link errors (cross-compiling for android)

Tags: android, c++, linker, android-ndk

I'm attempting to crosscompile a large opensource library for android. I've edited the source to include the android versions of libraries that are not shared, changed definitions of word sizes etc. and gotten all the individual files in the library to compile without errors/warnings.

On the final command that links all the object files into a single executable, I get a bunch of errors, all of the form complaining about undefined references to _Unwind_Resume and __emutls_get_address.

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly does this question relate (other than the error?) the answer provided uses something specific to the library that the op was trying to build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to static library libgcc_eh to the build process:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lgcc_eh
```